# How to unbind onbeforeunload event from all elements of the html body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onbeforeunload

How to unbind the beforeunload event from all elements of the html body. Kindly tell me , is there any way to unbind beforeunload event from every javascript function call . Please help me , I am stuck badly on this.

I am using the below code :

```js
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

j$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(window).bind("onbeforeunload", function() {
    return confirm("do you want to exit?", "true");
  });

  jQuery('a').on('click', function() {
    jQuery(window).unbind('onbeforeunload')
  });

  jQuery(window).bind('keydown keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 116) {
      jQuery(window).unbind('onbeforeunload');
    }
    if (e.which === 82 && e.ctrlKey) {
      jQuery(window).unbind('onbeforeunload');
    }
  });

  jQuery(window).mousedown(function(e) {
    if (e.button == 2) {
      jQuery(window).unbind('onbeforeunload');
    } else {
      jQuery(window).bind('onbeforeunload');
    }
  });

  jQuery("form").submit(function() {
    jQuery(window).unbind('onbeforeunload')
  });
  
  jQuery(document.body).unbind('onbeforeunload');
});
```

Comment: `beforeunload` is only an event fired on `window` object. If you want to unbind it, you need to handle all other events than can trigger it, as anchor click or shortcut pressed. So instead describe what's wrong with your code

Comment: I see, you need to bind/unbind `beforeunload`, not `onbeforeunload`...

Comment: Sir, I have tried the beforeunload and onbeforeunload both . Both didn't work. Sir, the thing wrong with my code is I am not able to unbind it from the body of the page using ......

jQuery(document.body).unbind('onbeforeunload');

Comment: There is no event `beforeunload` for the body, **only** for `window` object. So to unbind it, you need to use `$(window).unbind('beforeunload');`. Now in your code you have `jQuery(window).bind('onbeforeunload');`, which is wrong because like said the event is `beforeunload` and here you try to rebind it but without passing any handler reference, it has to be `jQuery(window).bind('onbeforeunload', handler);`. If you modificate your code and post a jsFiddle, it would be more simple for someoneelse to fix your issue.

Comment: But i guess, you won't be able anyway to catch all possible way to close the window. What if document isn't focused and user press some shortcut key? The window would be closed but no catchable event to unbind beforeunload would be fired. And then comes my question, in which case(s) do you expect the beforeunload event to be fired? Only if user click windwo closing tab/window buttons or what???